# error al instalar libreria en python

Tags: python, pip

estoy tratando de instalar librerias de modo offline, pero al hacerlo me arroja varios errores que no me queda claro como solucionarlo, ya instale varios de los MSV, aca el listado

- Características principales de C++ Buil Tools Actualizacion de C++
- 2019 Redistributable Bibliotecas con mitigaciones de Spectre de MSVC
- v142 - VS 2019 C++ para x64/x86(v14.29-16.10) Herramienta de CMake en
- C++ para Windows Herramientas de compilación de MSVC v142 - VS2019
- C++ para ARM64 (v14.29-16.10) Herramientas de compilación de MSVC
- v142 - VS2019 C++ para x64/x86(más recientes) Herramienta de
  compilacion de MSVC v142 - VS2019 C++ para x64/x86(v14.29-16.10) MSVC
- v140 - VS 2015 C++ Build Tools (v14.00) MSV v141 - VS 2017 C++ Build Tools (v14.16)
- SDK de Windows Universal CRT AddressSanitizer pra C++
- Entorno de tiempo de ejecución de C de Windows Universal

sin embargo me sigue presentando fallas la instalar , lo estoy realizando de esta manera

```
C:\librerias>pip install cx_Oracle-8.3.0.tar.gz
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Processing c:\librerias\cx_oracle-8.3.0.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]

      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.6.0 (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.6.0
      WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

Mi version Python 3.10.10 y pip (22.3.1) y setuptools (65.5.0)

Comment: Probaste instalar setuptools? `pip install setuptools`

Answer (score 1):

Una opción diferente a tratar de construir el módulo, es instalar el binario .whl [cx_Oracle precompilado](https://pypi.org/project/cx-Oracle/#files).

Para instalar un paquete wheel desde una fuente local

```
pip install C:/algun_directorio/el_paquete.whl
```

Ver: [Cómo instalar un paquete wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909082/1545868).

En caso de que hubiese conexión a internet, sería necesario el módulo wheel, el cual buscará en los repositorios los paquetes binarios como prioridad.

```
pip install --upgrade wheel
pip install cx_Oracle
```

---

El desarrollo de cx_Oracle [ha finalizado](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/628) y está disponible hasta Python 3.10, como tu caso.
Para python 3.7 o superior (incluyendo la actual 3.11) usa [oracledb](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html), en conjunto con [Oracle InstantClient](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html).
Archivos [oracledb en pypi](https://pypi.org/project/oracledb/#files)